# Double constraint in modular arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Find all integers $x$ such that $x ≡ 5 (\mod 8)$ and $x ≡ 73 (\mod 81)$.

Should I think like this:

$x = 5 + 8a$

$5 +8a = 73 + 81a → 68 = 72a$

After that I'm stuck.

Comment: Have you ever heard about Chinese Remainder Theorem? This is exactly what you need to solve your problem.

Comment: Do you agree with the new title I suggest ? In particular, the word "mathematics" doesn't bring any information : it is a mathematics' site!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's call that integer $n$ instead of $x$. We have some $x\in\Bbb{Z}$ such that:
$$n=8x+5$$
and another $y\in\Bbb{Z}$ such that:
$$n=81y+73$$
putting this together yields:
$$8x+5=81y+73$$
$$8x-81y=68$$
We now use the extended euclidean algorithm to obtain:
$$(x,y)=(-680+81k,-68-8k)$$
Which gives: 
$$n=8x+5=8(-680+81k)+5=-5440+648k+5=648k-5435$$
for all $k\in\Bbb{Z}$. Note you can also use $n=648k+397$, as $-5435\equiv397\pmod{648}$

Comment: No problem. By the way, if you think this answer was helpful you can upvote if you want ;)

Comment: Like this Mastream?

Comment: Yes, like that :)